# NuxtJS page title not change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a nuxtJS project and not much know about nuxt or vue, what I want is change page title, but it show one title for all page, that title belong to one component, I removed that title and now it show nothing. I put this code in header component

```
<script>
    export default {
    name: "header",
    head () {
        return {
            title: this.title
        }
    },
    data () {
        return {
            title: 'Hello World!'
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```

and in nuxtjs config :

```
module.exports = {
  head: {
    title: pkg.name
}
...
}
```

What I want, show title of each page dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

Your `nuxt.config.js` override title set in your page.

You should use titleTemplate in `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
head: {
  titleTemplate(titleChunk) {
    return titleChunk ? titleChunk : pkg.name
  }
}
```

By this way, you can also format title for every page with you site name:

```js
head: {
  titleTemplate(titleChunk) {
    return titleChunk ? `{pkg.name} - ${titleChunk}` : pkg.name
  }
}
```

`titleChunk` come from `head.title` of your page like you already do.

Answer (score 2):

There are only option to set the title dynamic base on your pages is like override the head function
Let me show you one example here

```
export default {
  ...
  head () {
    return {
      title: 'YOUR PAGE TITLE',
      meta: [
        { hid: 'og-title', property: 'og:title', content: 'YOUR PAGE TITLE },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

To prevent the overwrite parent meta fields, **your hid should be unique**

For more information, please visit the official document of the NuxtJs: **https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head/**

Answer (score 0):

I am using `nuxt version 2.15.7`. This syntax is working correctly for me:

> nuxt.config.js file

```js
head: {
        titleTemplate: '%s',
        title: 'info-book', // the title you define. you must put your package-name here, if you want that name. 
}
```

And then in the component that you want to define title dynamically, you have this code:

```js
head() {
    return {
      title: "info-book - " + this.titleHead,
    }
},

data () {
  return {
    titleHead: "dynamic-title"
  }
},
```